# Weird behaviour of Visual Studio using Python

Tags: python, visual-studio, function, scope

I haven't tested this exhaustively, but it seems like when I have a function in Python [in VS], and I decide to add something at the start of the fct after having already created the it, it won't let me without creating errors.

This is how my code is at first. I have this open in both VS and notepad++, works.

```
import httplib2, re

def search_for_Title(content) 

    searchBounds = re.compile('<title><!\[CDATA\[(.{1,100})\]\]></title>|<description>(.{1,400})</p>')

    Title = re.findall(searchBounds,content)

    return Title

def main():

    url = "http://www.economist.com/sections/international/rss.xml"

    h = httplib2.Http('.cache')
    content = h.request(url)

    titlesArray = search_for_Title(str(content))

    for i in titlesArray:
        print('Title: ' + i[0] + '\n Description: ' + i[1])


main()
```

I wanted to format the regex for better visibility, and therefore decided to create a string where I can use ''' to separate it (that was the idea).

As soon as I performed this step, I get errors in VS (for searchBounds 'unexpected indent' and 'cant assign to error expression' and a bunch of others further down).

(how the relevant code looks now)

```
 def search_for_Title(content):

    regexStr = '<title><!\[CDATA\[(.{1,100})\]\]></title>|<description>(.{1,400})</p>'

    searchBounds = re.compile(regexStr)

    Title = re.findall(searchBounds,content)

    return Title
```

But none in Notepad++...

I didn't set up anything for VS other than downloading python tools, could that be my error?

I can get it to work by simply copying what I've got in notepad++ (the exact same!), but I would prefer to not have to use two IDEs at the same time.

PS It seems like UTF-8 in Python cannot decode a 'ã'. Ie can't take such a string, any way around this?

Comment: Try removing the space before `def`

Comment: that was a typo, my bad, problem remains

Comment: Make sure you're using consistent indentation. Either all spaces or all tabs. Don't mix the two.